# Embedding MATLAB code in a browser?

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment

Can I run MATLAB code in a browser somehow? I can always convert the code to flash or php or Java but I am just being lazy. I would like to embed the MATLAB simulations I have in a browser somehow. doable?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [MATLAB Builder NE](http://www.mathworks.com/products/netbuilder/) for that. As you can see in [this page](http://www.mathworks.com/products/netbuilder/description4.html):

> You can integrate a MATLAB based .NET component with a service-oriented Web application using the Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) API

Answer (score 0):

Here's a dumb question rather than an answer: if you serve Matlab to a client browser, where do you expect it to run ?  I guess you must expect it to run on a machine with at least the MCR (Matlab Compiler Runtime) installed ?

The Mathworks used to sell a product called Matlab Web Server; but discontinued products aren't much of an answer either.

Comment: yeah I was hoping for some kind of plugin which prompts the user to install the runtime if not installed and then run everything in the browser